# Not able to access SQL Server stored procedure output parameter in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to get a value of output parameter which I used in my stored procedure, but I am not getting it. I've been trying hard but could not figure it out. The program is not throwing any error, but in the end, the value of `_clientCode` is null (Refer screenshot):

[image]

I need your support, please help me to find out where I need to change.

```
public string getData5(string icuser)
{
    string _clientCode;

    SqlDataReader dataReader;
            
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Server=xxx-dbprod;DataBase=TCS;Integrated Security=True;";
                // conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = tcr-dbprod; Initial Catalog = TCS; Integrated Security = True;";
                //conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = conn;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "[dbo].[spTCRGetClientCode]";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@icUserID", icuser);
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@clientCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 300));
    command.Parameters["@clientCode"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        int i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        _clientCode = Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@clientCode"].Value);
        conn.Close();

        return _clientCode;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return null;
        //conn.Close();
        //DbConnection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I explained in my question detail and attached the screenshot for your help.

[image]

Comment: Where's the screenshot? And **why** are you executing your stored procedure **twice** - `ExecuteNonQuery()` is intended for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements that do not return a result set - why are you calling this first - and then `ExecuteReader()` (which is for a `SELECT` statement returning a result set) just following it?? Executing **once** would be sufficient ....

Comment: feel free to attach the procedure code, maybe the issue is there

Comment: Either do `ExecuteReader` or `ExecuteNonQuery` not both. If you do the former, make sure to fully read the reader and call `NextResult` in order to finish executing the procedure. Side notes: `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` need to be disposed with `using`. Shorter version of your code: `command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@clientCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 300)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();
                    dt.Load(sdr);
                    conn.Close();
                    _clientCode = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                    return _clientCode;
                }

Comment: I tried to make little change and that works! now. Thanks for all your quick response

Comment: Your execution returns value as *resultset*, not as *output parameter*. That seems to be the problem. In your sp code you need to do something like: select @clientCode = 'somevalue' from anothertable . this will assign the value to your parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ExecuteReader` and `ExecuteNonQuery` for a command, please review your code and use one of ways.

You can use two below my code and replace with your code to solve your problem.

Your code:

```
int i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
_clientCode = Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@clientCode"].Value);
```

This is my code - option #1:

```
int i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
_clientCode = Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@clientCode"].Value);
dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Option #2:

```
int i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

using (SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read()) 
    { 
        /* do whatever with result set data here */ 
    }
}

_clientCode = Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@clientCode"].Value);
```

[SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?source=recommendations&view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

[SqlCommand.ExecuteReader Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

Description for `ExecuteNonQuery` and `ExecuteReader` from [ExecuteReader, ExecuteNonQuery and Executescalar in ADO.NET](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/executereader-executenonquery-and-executescalar-in-adonet) by [Mageshwaran R](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/members/mageshwaran-r)

> ##### ExecuteNonQuery:
>
> ExecuteNonQuery method is used to execute SQL Command or the
> stored procedure performs, INSERT, UPDATE or Delete operations. It
> doesn't return any data from the database. Instead, it returns an
> integer specifying the number of rows inserted, updated or deleted.
>
> ##### ExecuteReader:
>
> ExecuteReader method is used to execute a SQL Command or
> stored procedure returns a set of rows from the database.

Comment: *"hasn't logical use ExecuteNonQuery() and ExecuteReader() to a sqlcommand,you must review your business and use one of ways"* that sentence doesn't make any sense I'm afraid.